# Error al querer coger valores de un JSON: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Quiero poder coger los valores del JSON de Reportes.

**reportes.json**

```
[
    {
        "titulo": "Error de ejecucion",
        "fecha": "20/10/1995",
        "ruta": "C:/Pablo/Diselxico",
        "prioridad": 1,
        "funcion": "funcion patata",
        "comentario" : "to guapo",
        "solucionado" : false
    },
    {
        "titulo": "Funcion no acabada",
        "fecha": "21/09/2018",
        "ruta": "C:/Dislexia/Daltonico",
        "prioridad": 1,
        "funcion": "funcion caja",
        "comentario" : "to fea",
        "solucionado" : false
    },
    {
        "titulo": "Demasiados IF",
        "fecha": "1/01/2019",
        "ruta": "C:/Pablo/Sida",
        "prioridad": 1,
        "funcion": "funcion correa",
        "comentario" : "to guapoto guapoto guapoto guapoto guapoto guapoto guapo",
        "solucionado" : false
    }
]
```

**reporte.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//Archivo json
import * as _reportes from "../archivos json/reportes.json";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesService {
  private reportes;

  constructor() { 
    this.setReportes();
  }

  private setReportes() {
    this.reportes = _reportes;
  }

  getReportes():Reporte[] {
    return this.reportes;
}

  addReporte(reporte:Reporte):void {
    this.reportes.push(reporte);
  }

}

export interface Reporte {
  titulo:string;
  fecha:Date;
  ruta:string;
  prioridad:number;
  funcion:string;
  comentario:string;
  solucionado:boolean;
}
```

**reporte.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ServicesService, Reporte } from '../../service/services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reporte',
  templateUrl: './reporte.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reporte.component.css']
})

export class ReporteComponent implements OnInit {
  reporte:Reporte;
  reportes:Reporte[];

  constructor(private reportesService:ServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reportes = this.reportesService.getReportes();
  }

}
```

**reporte.component.html**

```
<div class="container-div">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li *ngFor="let reporte of reportes" class="list-group-item">
        {{reporte.titulo}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar la aplicación web me sale el siguiente error en consola y no me saca las variables que quiero de reporte:

```
ReporteComponent.html:20 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3185)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22003)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23264)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23226)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23860)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23820)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ReporteComponent.html:20)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23812)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23208)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23449)
```

Comment: Intenta: import _reportes from "../archivos json/reportes.json"; sin el * as

Comment: Era exactamente eso, muchas gracias!

Comment: Genial voy a dicionar como respuesta asi podes cerrar el post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando importas un json solo con el nombre de la variable podes:

```
import _reportes from "../archivos json/reportes.json";
```

no es necesario colocar un * as, porque no estas exportando nada desde un json.